# Enable ubuntu linux server cache with Apache

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ubuntu-16.04

Good morning. I need help with something. Today I use a Ubuntu 16.04 linux server and I'm trying to enable caching on my server in order to increase the Google Page Speed score. But I could not.

On the server I already installed the apache expires and headers modules by running the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod expires
sudo a2enmod headers
```

After installation I checked that the modules are there. I also restarted Apache.

But on my website when passing the code via .htacess

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 month" 
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 7 days"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Google Pagespeed keeps pointing out that TTL Cache is not enabled. Can someone help me? This procedure above was the only one I have done so far.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuqH8.png)

Comment: Is the website public? Can we browse to it to see what headers are being received? Can you also include a screenshot of the PageSpeed errors? I think your htaccess code looks ok, but maybe the headers aren't being written, or being overwritten? Do you have cache-control enabled? This link may be helpful >  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers#:~:text=The%20Cache%2DControl%20header%20is,on'%20caching%20in%20the%20browser.&text=While%20the%20Cache%2DControl%20header,resource%20is%20no%20longer%20valid

Comment: Hello, @JimDiroffII sorry for the delay in answering you. The site is public: URL: https://conteudo.movidesk.com/

Comment: I also placed a link with the Google Pagespeed image